# Error in uploading file using PHP

Tags: php, post, file-upload

I am asking the user to upload a file, through the following form making a POST Request to another page Upload.php

```
<form name="input" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
    <input type="file" name="file" /> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

At Upload.php, I use the data filled in the previous form to make an POST Request using Curl function for which I have written the following code:

```
$data = array(
        "username" => $username,
        "password" => $password,
        "title" => $title,
        "srcfile" => "@".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$response=curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
```

This way I am able to upload the file successfully but the file uploaded has a name without any extension which is set by this

> $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']

and thus I am not able to use the file on the server.

How should I use the file obtained from the POST Request to make another POST Request?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Looking at your code, you seem to have lacking understanding of how file uploads work in PHP. Take a look at the manual, try again and update your question if you still have difficulties achieving what you seek: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Have also tried using "srcfile" => "@".$_FILES['srcfile']['tmp_name'].";type=".$_FILES['srcfile']['type'] but still not working

Comment: I came across this **PHP bug** though I am using PHP 5.3.1 https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48962

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the above case is that though we can have the file using $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], however, the file extension is not the same as that of original file and even the following code does not work which should run as filed in this bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48962 in PHP 5.0

```
"srcfile" => "@".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].";filename=".$_FILES['file']['name'].";type=".$_FILES['file']['type']
```

I have finally used the following solution to solve the above problem:

STEP 1: Save the file sent through the form's POST request in a folder temporarily on the server or your machine.

STEP 2: Now use the path where file has been saved temporarily to make a POST request using CURL for which the code is used same as above mentioned with changes in file location.

```
"srcfile" => "@".temp_file_path
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_FILE['file']` is an array, which means `complex types` for `SimpleXMLElement`'s properties.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the file, encode it and assign the encoded value to the XML element. For example you can use something like:

```
$xml->file = base64_encode( file_get_contents( $_FILE['file'][ 'tmp_name' ] ) );
```

Of course in a real code you should add error checking etc.

Comment: This answer won't work in my case as I have to also specify the file uploaded on the server as "srcfile" parameter in the POST Request accompained with the file name.